# Python 2 export csv with japanese test

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, encoding, utf-8

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])

    test_jp = u'\u30a2\u30af\u30bb\u30b5\u30ea\u30fc'
    print(test_jp)
    print(type(test_jp))
    print(repr(test_jp))
    print('-------------------')
    print(test_jp.encode('utf-8'))    
    print(test_jp.encode('cp932'))

    '''
    print(test_jp.decode('utf-8'))
    spamwriter.writerow(test_jp)

    Causeing ERROR
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters
    in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
    '''
```

I have tried spamwriter.writerow(test_jp.encode('utf-8')).

But the output is garbled -> 'ã‚¢ã‚¯ã‚»ã‚µãƒªãƒ¼'.

I want the output csv content is 'アクセサリー'

How should I do? (spamwriter.writerow(test_jp) doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in a `list` for writerow then `test_jp.encode("utf-8")` will work, writerow expects an iterable so it is iterating over the string writing each byte:

```
spamwriter.writerow([test_jp.encode("utf-8")])
```

You can see when we iterate over it we also get strange output:

```
In [6]: for ch in test_jp.encode("utf-8"):
              print ch
   ...:     

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�


In [7]: print test_jp.encode("utf-8")
アクセサリー
```

Tested and working:

```
$ cat eggs.csv 
Spam |Lovely Spam| |Wonderful Spam|
アクセサリー
```

Comment: i have tried your code, but result is garbled again but not アクセサリー

Comment: This is not going to work, "print test_jp.encode("utf-8")" works fine, but when I experimented myself "spamwriter.writerow([test_jp.encode("utf-8")])" failed anyway. I think something like the code from [Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#examples) section for CSV module should be implemented.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, sorry. Re-checked it one more time, works for me as well. I had the issue because I tried codecs.open()

Comment: it is sitll garbled. is possible to run spamwriter.writerow(test_jp) by skipping 'ascii' encode to avoid error?

Comment: @yves, did you wrap it in a list  and done it as I have in my answer?

Comment: @yves, do exactly as I have in my answer, the for loop to to show you why your method does **not** work.

Comment: spamwriter.writerow([test_jp.encode("utf-8")]) result same as spamwriter.writerow(test_jp.encode("utf-8"))

Comment: weird, both prints - print(test_jp.encode('utf-8')) and print(test_jp) work fine for me, can it be connected with OS or system locale? I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @yves, where are you running this?

Comment: Python 2.7.9 IDLE with windows 7

Comment: well.. under win7 print fails but csv file saved almost correctly.. At least Windows notepad show correct data, but MS Excel shows garbled output.
@yves looks like this is more Windows related quirk when python's, I have no any ideas how this could be fixed on Win, you can try to google Windows console encoding issues probably..

Comment: @yves, then it is a windows encoding issue.